# Validate a username on Linux using PAM

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

I know there has been many questions regarding authentication schemes using PAM on Linux and I also have a working copy for a username/password auth.

I want to know if we can validate "just" the username alone...given that I don't even create a password when I create that particular user in Linux. If Yes, let me know how to go about it. A few code snippets would be really great. Thanks!

P.S. Right now I authenticate by passing values through strings (each for username and password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I figured, an easy method, and it might be different than anybody else's logic. 

- Take that "username" only and try to create a user using Linux's own system call. 
- If the user creation succeeds --> the user never existed (it solves my problem of creating a user without a password).  
- If the user creation fails --> the user already exists and it doesn't create. 
The system will return this and you must grab the return value to move on to the next step of your program).

Let me know if this can be made more refined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pam_securetty that check if user id is 0, if the user doesnt exist -this check fails and therefore its validate the username. Add to /etc/pam.d/login 
`auth require pam_securetty.so`